# How can I fix this problem, it is URP empty project, Unity 2021.2.7f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unable to find player assembly: D:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.7f1\Projects\EpicGame\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Also, try to post the full error log and the code that is causing the issue. Furthermore, I suggest you to take a look at these: [how to write an mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.